# Disable 2FA while at home

Tags: security, pam, radius, yubikey

I have two factor authentication setup for login on my laptop using a Yubikey setup for U2F. Now, while I love the security, it is a pain to use the key while sitting at home. Is there a way for my laptop to detect that I am at home and only required a password?

I have looked at possibly using a RADIUS server with the RADIUS pam module, but I believe that would require me to type in another username and password which doesn't improve the usability. Other than that, I have not found any ways of achieving my goal.

Comment: Get inspiration from how it's done for phones.  If you have an AP at home, disable 2FA when you're connected to it; if you have an NFC reader, use an NFC sticker; if you have a GPS attached use the coordinates, etc.

Comment: That is not a bad idea, but I fear I am going to need to write my own pam module to detect when I am connected to a certain AP. Either my google-foo is lacking and a module that can do that is already out there or no one has written it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Sato's first and second proposals are good ways here, but the first one is maybe the easiest but requires a pam module (Yodal) and its maintenance to work. 
Sato Katsura's answer in comments about using AP for disabling 2FA

> Get inspiration from how it's done for phones. If you have an AP at home, disable 2FA when you're connected to it;

### Alternative approaches

Sato's idea in comments about NFC sticker with NFC reader to ease login at home

> if you have an NFC reader, use an NFC sticker;

Sato's idea about GPS which I think is most inaccurate here, and consumes also much battery, and also requires the use of smartphone

> if you have a GPS attached use the coordinates, etc.

### Discussion about the question

To disable 2FA even at home can compromise security. 
In the strictest security sense, I think 2FA login should not be disabled even at home. 
Simple is just effective.

- What are the amount of false negatives in each step in security?
- How does the complexity of the system and the maintenance of the pam module for AP affect the security?